# Best method to bulk load (5 millions) into Janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlinpython

Doing some stress testing on Janusgraph and required to load est 5 million vertex and edges. Using faker python to generate the fake data and will like to know which is the best method to load such bulk chuck of data? I tried to load the data using the console but getting weird results and timeout.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using the Gremlin Python client from the tags. A fairly common technique is to use a multi threaded (or multi process) Python application that sends data to the graph in batches (perhaps 50 to 100 `addV` or `addE` at a time). It's not clear from your question if you are using Gremlin Server or not. If you are using Gremlin Server you may want to configure the `gremlinPool` parameter in the YAML file to have sufficient workers for the class of machine you have it running on. It should not take too long to load 5 million vertices and edges in this fashion. If overall time to load the vertices and edges is not a concern, a single thread sending batches of 50 to 100 at a time is still reasonably efficient.